# Cannot modify header information when I try my site with www

Tags: warnings

When I try to reach my website and include www in it's address I get this error:

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../wp-content/themes/BulletPressWP/framework/includes/post-meta-details.php:1) in .../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896
```

If I try address without www everything is OK.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme. Does the behaviour go away?  If so, switch back to your theme. If the behaviour comes back, then your theme is the culprit. If it's still working right, then turn your plugins back on one at a time till you find the problem. Now you know what's causing the issue. Check the plugin or theme's support forum to see if the issue has been reported before.

Comment: My first guess is that there's a plugin or something that does a redirection of some kind -- perhaps `wp_redirect()` -- from `www.example.com` to `example.com`. Redirects can't happen if content has already been sent to the browser. You might be looking for a late call to a redirection.

Comment: On my other network site, I don't have this problem and the redirection you mentioned happens. I think now it's time to find the plugin.

Comment: Well the problem is with theme, not the plugins. I renamed plugins folder and the problem remained.

Comment: It could be something as simple as a newline character after a PHP file's closing `?>`. I've taken to writing my PHP files without a closing `?>`, since it's not required by the interpreter.

Comment: Try reviewing this codex to solve header already sent problem: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F